# Get the Most Popular Trigrams for Each Row in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nltk

I'm new to python and trying to get a list of the most popular trigrams for each row in a Pandas dataframe from a column named ['Question'].

I've come close to what I need, but I am unable to get the popularity counts at a row level. Ideally I'd just like to keep the ngrams with a minimum frequency about 1.

Minimum Reproduceable Example:

```
import pandas as pd import nltk

data = {
    "question": [
        "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog",
        "Waltz, bad nymph, for quick jigs vex.",
        "Glib jocks quiz nymph to vex dwarf.",
        "Sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow.",
        "How vexingly quick daft zebras jump!",
    ] }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


df["bigrams"] = df['question'].apply(lambda row: list(nltk.bigrams(row.split(' ')))) 

print(df)
```

Current Output:

```
 question                                            bigrams
0  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog  [(The, quick), (quick, brown), (brown, fox), (...
1        Waltz, bad nymph, for quick jigs vex.  [(Waltz,, bad), (bad, nymph,), (nymph,, for), ...
2          Glib jocks quiz nymph to vex dwarf.  [(Glib, jocks), (jocks, quiz), (quiz, nymph), ...
3        Sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow.  [(Sphinx, of), (of, black), (black, quartz,), ...
4         How vexingly quick daft zebras jump!  [(How, vexingly), (vexingly, quick), (quick, d...
```

Desired Output: (Or close to it - I'm not sure how best to represent the frequency counts!)

```
 question                                            bigrams
0  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog  [(The, quick,1), (quick, brown,1), (brown, fox), (...
1        Waltz, bad nymph, for quick jigs vex.  [(Waltz,, bad,1), (bad, nymph,2), (nymph,, for), ...
1          Glib jocks quiz nymph to vex dwarf.  [(Glib, jocks,1), (jocks,quiz,2), 
1        Sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow.  [(Sphinx, of,1), (of, black,2), (black, quartz,), ...
1         How vexingly quick daft zebras jump!  [(How, vexingly.1), (vexingly, quick,1), (quick, d...
```

Comment: But the bigram (The, quick) appearing only one time in your string in question, how it can be 3?

Comment: I wanted to keep the output short, and thought it got my point across. But I'll edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input data (for demo purpose, all strings have been cleaned):

```py
data = ["she wants to sing she wants to act she wants to dance",
        "if you sing I will smile if you laugh I will smile if you love I will smile"]

df = pd.DataFrame({"question": data})
```

Compute frequency distribution of bigrams with `nltk.FreqDist`:

```
bigram_freq = lambda s: list(nltk.FreqDist(nltk.bigrams(s.split(" "))).items())

out = df['question'].apply(bigram_freq).explode()
out = pd.DataFrame(out.to_list(), index=out.index, columns=["question", "bigrams"])
```

Output result:

```py
>>> out
        question  bigrams
0   (she, wants)        3
0    (wants, to)        3
0     (to, sing)        1
0    (sing, she)        1
0      (to, act)        1
0     (act, she)        1
0    (to, dance)        1
1      (if, you)        3
1    (you, sing)        1
1      (sing, I)        1
1      (I, will)        3
1  (will, smile)        3
1    (smile, if)        2
1   (you, laugh)        1
1     (laugh, I)        1
1    (you, love)        1
1      (love, I)        1
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The issue is, I need the frequency for each row in the dataframe, similar to how it appears in teh desired output. Essenitally I need to bigram each row independantly. Appreciate the help though!

Comment: Just try: `df['question'].apply(bigram_freq)` but keep in mind, it's hard to do something with this representation.